# ¿Cómo aplicar notificaciones locales con datepicker en xamarin forms a una aplicación de recordatorios?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

Necesito ayuda. Estoy trabajando en una aplicación que tiene que controlar el día y la hora para entregar las tareas. La lógica de la aplicación es la siguiente: el usuario debe ingresar la fecha y la hora para realizar su tarea. Después de esto, la aplicación debe mostrar una notificación local el día y la hora en que el usuario ingresó, pero aún así no puede hacer que eso suceda. sugerencias

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PruebaNotificacion"
             x:Class="PruebaNotificacion.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>

        <DatePicker x:Name="txtFechaPicker"></DatePicker>
        <TimePicker x:Name="txtHoraPicker"></TimePicker>

        <DatePicker x:Name="txtFechaPickerA" IsVisible="False"></DatePicker>
        <DatePicker x:Name="txtFechaSistema" IsVisible="False"></DatePicker>

        <Button Text="Send!" x:Name="btnSendNotify" Clicked="BtnSendNotify_Clicked"/>

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Esto es el archivo xaml en donde estan mis controles datepicker y timepicker

```
using System;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Plugin.LocalNotifications;

namespace PruebaNotificacion
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            txtFechaPicker.MinimumDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
        public  void BtnSendNotify_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int _dia = txtFechaPicker.Date.Day;
            int _mes = txtFechaPicker.Date.Month;
            int _year = txtFechaPicker.Date.Year;
            int _hora = txtHoraPicker.Time.Hours;
            int _minutos = txtHoraPicker.Time.Minutes;
            int _seg = txtHoraPicker.Time.Seconds;

        DateTime _fechaA = new DateTime(_year, _mes, _dia, _hora, _minutos,_seg);

        txtFechaPickerA.Date = _fechaA;
        txtFechaSistema.Date = DateTime.Now;

        Notificacion();

    }
    public void Notificacion()
    {
        if (txtFechaPickerA == txtFechaSistema)
        {
            CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show("My Baby Safe", "Ya es tiempo de la vacuna de su bebé");
        }

    }

}
}
```

Este es el código C# del archivo `xaml`
lo que no logro hacer es una correcta comparación de la variable `_fechaA` y la propiedad `DateTime.Now`, y que a pesar que la aplicación se cierre se esté ejecutando en segundo plano ese proceso de evaluación para que llegada la hora exacta la notificación se le muestre al usuario

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias explicar un poco mejor que necesitas? y mostrar que intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: Veras, estoy comenzando en lo que es programación y me pareció buena idea incursionar con el desarrollo de  aplicaciones móviles, y estoy utilizando xamarin en visual studio, la aplicación que estoy tratando de realizar es sobre recordatorios, algo así como la típica aplicación que te recuerda que debes de tomar agua o hacer ejercicio a través de una notificación local @gbianchi

Comment: Eso es genial, y que investigaste e intentaste hasta ahora? en el sitio se pide que muestres lo que intentaste e investigaste hasta ahora para encausarte por donde necesites

Comment: Si queres agregar informacion a tu pregunta, usa el boton [edit], y agrega todo en la pregunta. Los comentarios son solo para aclaraciones

Comment: ok esta bien y gracias por la aclaración

Comment: ahora si veras lo que deseo hacer es algo simple, comparar un datepicker que el usuario llenara con la fecha que desee y un timepicker con la hora que desee recibir la notificación y luego almacenarlo en otro datepicker para compararlo con la hora del sistema del dispositivo

Comment: Todo lo que tengas que explicar, explicalo en la pregunta. Ahora, lo que haces, parece hacerlo.

Comment: No deberias comparar los vaores que estan en txtFechaPickerA.Date con txtFechaSistema.Date ?? tu if solo esta comparando si son el mismo control, que claramente no lo son

Comment: y por lo general, no uses como nombre txt para un date picker.. si no, parece que es un textbox ;)

Comment: y que nombre debería de utilizar para el datepicker ?

Comment: puedes usar el que te plazca.. pero a mi me llevo a confundirme. yo por lo general uso dt para un date... pero un txt seguro es un textbox ;)

Comment: ok gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Puedes usar [DependencyService](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) para la creación de la notificación, te interesa la hora en que lo seleccionó?

Comment: Realmente ya logre realizar lo que deseaba sin necesidad de utilizar el DependencyService